# VisualStudio Intellisense issues with JavaScript object that are part of a namespace

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, oop, namespaces, intellisense

I'm giving it my best shot at categorizing this correctly. I'm running into an intellisense issue where VisualStudio2013 (VS) won't suggest internal variables in certain situations.

Example: (This one works just fine)

```
function foo(){
    this._someVar = true;
}
var bar = new foo();
bar._someVar // Autocomplete is working here.
```

Example (This one is not suggesting ._someVar)

```
var namespace = {};
namespace.foo = function(){
this._someVar = true;
}
var bar = new namespace.foo();
bar._som-   // Autocomplete is not woking here.
```

Has anyone else run across this issue? How did you get around it or fix it? I've been searching for a fix for about an hour now. Thanks.